# How to reload TabMenu after filling model to refresh scroll icons

Tags: angular, primeng

**What I want to do:** I'm trying to fill a p-tabmenu with items created from values in a database. And refresh the component to show scroll icons.

Here is the original example of PrimeNG [Original PrimeNG Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tabmenu-demo?file=README.md)

To show the problem I forked the example of primeng on Stackblitz: [My fork of the example with the problem](https://primeng-tabmenu-demo-hc97nb.stackblitz.io)

**What I did:** First I want to call a webservice in the ngOnInit() method. To simulate this I put a delayed filling method in the example.

Note: I didn't initialize the model of the TabMenu. After the delay the tabs are created accordingly to the model. But there are no scroll icons on the left or right to navigate to items in the back.

**The Problem:** If I set the model with a delay witout initializing it first it won't be scrollable.

If I initialize the model beforehand with a for loop with many tabs and then change the model it works.

**Question:** Is there a way to reload the tabMenu component after I set the model (and after the user changes the window size) so the scrollbars appear only if the tabs are bigger than the screen?

Comment: I don't know why but i can't open your forked example

Comment: Interesting It works for me in Edge but in Google Chrome it doesn't. Anyway I found an unexpected solution today. I'll post it later.